# Cannot dynamically add select element to dynamically created <div>

Tags: javascript

Ok so I want to do something simple in JavaScript, but I am getting an eror.

I want to dynamically create a div and then add another div plus a select control to it. But see the line I've marked with the error. When I include that line, I get the indicated error. What am I doing wrong? (I've simplified the code in the

```js
myDiv = BuildContainerDiv();
myLabel = BuildLabel();
myDropdown = BuildDropdown();

myDiv.appendChild(myLabel);   //Works fine.
myDiv.appendChild(myDropdown);  // ERROR:  Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'

BuildContainerDiv: function () {
   div = document.createElement('div');
   div.id = "MyDiv";
   div.name = "MyDiv";
   div.style.padding = "10px";
   div.style.float = "left";
   return div;
},
BuildLabel: function () {
    var lab = document.createElement('div');
    lab.id = "mylabel";
    lab.name = "mylabel";
    lab.innerHTML = "Some text:";        
    return lab;
},
BuildDropdown: function () {
    var select = document.createElement('select');
    select.id = "myselect";
    select.name = "myselect";
 
    var option1 = document.createElement("option");
    option1.value = "0";
    option1.innerHTML = "(none)";
    select.appendChild(option1);
    //.....
    var option5 = document.createElement("option");
    option5.value = "0";
    option5.innerHTML = "all";
    select.appendChild(option5);        
    return select;
},
```

Comment: I have the code here https://jsfiddle.net/d39x6fey/ and its working. I only changed it so it could be ran stand alone

Comment: You'll need to add the relevant HTML so we can know what your DOM references actually reference and the hierarchy of those elements.

Comment: I can't seem to find the problem with your jsfiddle code. It seems to be working. Can you more clearly define your problem?

Comment: The code I've added is part of a much, much bigger file. Let me try to find/provide some more code that I think might be relevant.
I did not try the code outside of that huge file, I assumed it would not work, but clearly it worked for you and @imvain2.

Answer (score 0):

Silly error on my part. In my original post, I noted a function I was using called BuildDropdown. The problem was that I had another function with the same name in another part of the file, and it did not return a Node but plain html:

```
BuildDropdown: function () {
    var ctl= '<select name="MyDropDown" id="MyDropDown">';
    //...
    return ctl+ '</select >';
},
```

This function was an earlier attempt and I forgot to delete it, and this older method was somehow being called. Since it was in fact not returning a node, the error was accurate. Apologies for your time wasted.